# Facebook response is error_code=1 Error 1349040 Invalid Application ID: The specified application ID is invalid

Tags: facebook, error-code

I'm new to programming facebook applications. I'm trying to do a simple thing such as login to my page through facebook. And I'd done most of code work and achieved to connect to facebook, but then I'd got error. Error says my appID is invalid (void). But the one I'd provided is same as in my application page on developers.facebook.com. Secret also is the same.

All i want to do is to get facebook userID when he is logged and compare it to my database to log in proper user. I don't know what else to check. Or what else can I provide to you, so it can help solve this problem.

regards

I had found solution here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/112163982233944

Comment: Many things can cause this.  Be sure to go in and check the settings for the app, many times I see where people don't have that setup correctly.  Additional things to add to your report: What type of app is it (canvas, page tab, mobile)?  What framework are you using (JS SDK, PHP, C#, etc)? What method of login are you using (PHP generated URLs, Login social plugin, FB.login() JS call, etc)?

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I had found solution here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/112163982233944

Comment: You should also indicate in your question what type of user (test/real) was getting the error.  Most of us assume real user as so few people use the test user accounts.

Comment: I was using real user (mine account) but I didn't notice that I'd set application into sandbox mode.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  You should answer your own question so this doesn't appear on the open questions list.  Or, if you want, you can delete it.